# MongoDB custom double precision

Tags: java, mongodb, double

I have my service set up so that I am only ever sending doubles in the format XXXX.XX, they correctly map to Document, however when they're persisted to the DB the double displays as "fieldName" : 200.0500000000000100

Is there a way to dictate the precision that mongoDB shows for it's doubles to prevent it creating this extra accuracy?

Thanks

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: read this: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-monetary-data/

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, the mongo documentation holds a few suggestions :)